# vim, inserting line number at specific line

Tags: vim

I am testing few fortran codes by including print statements at various places. I also want to include a line number in the print statement, like:

```
...
write(*,*)'[current line #] I am here'
.....
.....
write(*,*)'[current line #] I am here too'
```

currently, I am inserting the line number manually by looking at the status bar. Is there any macro for the same?

Answer (score 6):

A simple expression mapping will do:

```
:inoremap <expr> <F11> line('.')
```

Or, if you prefer a complete abbreviation (type `debug` + <kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger it):

```
:inoreabbrev <expr> debug "write(*,*)'" . line('.')
```

Comment: Note to self: investigate `<expr>` mappings.

Comment: I take it this would be largely equivalent to doing `inoremap <F11> <C-r>=line('.')<CR>`?

Comment: For a simple mapping (like here), you're right. For complex ones, there's a difference in when the expression is evaluated. I even had to combine both kinds occasionally to get the right evaluation order.

Answer (score 3):

In *insert* mode, you can do:

```
<C-r>=line('.')<CR>
```

In *normal* mode, you can create a simple mapping:

```
nnoremap <F9> :execute ":normal 0iline number: " . line('.') . " hello world"<CR>
```

which outputs this when executed on line 39:

```
line number: 39 hello world
```

See `:help line()` and, more generally, `:help functions`.

Comment: Thanks. For python, `nnoremap <F9> :execute ":normal 0iprint\(\"line number: " . line('.') . " hello world\", file=sys.stderr\)"<CR>`. With a file name, `nnoremap <F9> :execute ":normal 0iprint\(\"line number: " . line('.') . ""expand("%:p")" hello world\", file=sys.stderr\)"<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

You can include `line('.')` inside your macro, which returns the cursor line number.

Comment: you mean paste it in vimrc? can you pls elaborate!

Comment: No, I meant to include it on any macro/abbreviation you are using, as the ones in the new answers provided by Ingo and romainl.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the link http://crueltown.com/wordpress/?p=40
I was requiring this.
Thank you all the answers.